# When I use mvn to build cnosdb flight sql jadc access, there is always no class file generated

Tags: java, maven, jdbc, cnosdb

When I use mvn to build cnosdb flight sql jadc access, there is always no class file generated.what the promblem?

At first, I exec as follow:

```
mvn package
```

and then

```
java -cp ./target/jdbc-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com/cnosdb/Main
```

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.cnosdb.Main
```

finnally, I'm check the mune,there is no class.

```
$ tree ./
./
├── pom.xml
├── src
│   └── java
│       └── com
│           └── cnosdb
│               └── Main.java
└── target
    ├── jdbc-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
    └── maven-archiver
        └── pom.properties
```

Answer (score 1):

the class generation step should be implemented in the maven compile stage, please check the maven logs and see if there has compile messages.